# can i paginate data retrieved from api with yajra laravel

Tags: api, laravel-7, yajra-datatable

I am consuming api to get products using Laravel/yajra package but it get 6k entries every time can i get pagenumber from yarjra request to paginate manualy

**Api Consumption**

I want to add pagenumber to my api request when i click on yajra pagination links like in commented line below

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
    
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $response = Http::accept('application/json')->withHeaders(
                [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token
                ]
            )->get($this->apiurl . '/products');
        //->get($this->apiurl . '/products'.'?page='$pagnenumber);
            $response = json_decode($response);
            if ($response->status == 200) {
                $data = $response->products;
            } else {
                $data = [];
            }
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                    $btn =  '<div class="btn-group mb-5">' .
                        '<button type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Action</button>' .
                        '<div class="dropdown-menu">'
                        . '<a href="' . route("products.edit", $row->id) . '" data-type="products" id="edtbtn-' . $row->id . '" class="dropdown-item" data-bs-original-title="Edit"><i class="ti-marker-alt"></i> Edit</a>'
                        . '<a href="' . route("productview", $row->id) . '" data-type="products"  class="dropdown-item" data-bs-original-title="Edit"><i class="ti-eye"></i> View</a>'
                        . '<a href="' . route("drawbc", $row->bc) . '" target="_blank"   class="dropdown-item" data-bs-original-title="Edit"><i class="ti-layout-column3-alt"></i>barcode label</a>'
                        . '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dltbtn-' . $row->id . '" data-type="products" class="text-danger dropdown-item deltbtn" data-bs-original-title="Delete" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"><i class="ti-trash"></i> Delete</a>'
                        //. '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>'

                        . '</div>'
                        . '</div>';
                    //$btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dltbtn-' . $row->id . '" data-type="products" class="text-danger deltbtn" data-bs-original-title="Delete" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"><i class="ti-trash"></i></a>';



                    return $btn;
                })
                ->addColumn('active', function ($row) {
                    $actclass = $row->isact == 1 ? 'active' : '';
                    $boolclass = $row->isact == 1 ? 'true' : 'false';
                    //$html = '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle' .$row->isact == 1 ? 'active' : '' .'" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="'.  $row->isact == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' . '" autocomplete="off"></button><div class="handle"></div></button>';
                    $html = '<button type="button" aria-id="productid-' . $row->id . '" aria-id="productid-' . $row->id . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-toggle ' . $actclass . ' activate" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="' . $boolclass . '"  data-on-text="active" data-off-text="Inactive" autocomplete="off"><div class="handle"></div></button>';


                    return $html;
                })->addColumn('color', function ($row) {
                    if(isset($row->color)){
                    return $row->color->nm;
                    }else{
                        return '-';
                    }
                })->addColumn('size', function ($row) {
                    
                    if(isset($row->size)){
                    return $row->size->nm;
                    }else{
                        return '-';
                    }
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action', 'active'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        $response = Http::accept('application/json')->withHeaders(
            [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token
            ]
        )->get($this->apiurl . '/attributes');
        $response = json_decode($response);
        //return $response;
        $attributes = [];
        if ($response->status == 200) {
            $attributes = $response->attributes;
        }
        $data = Http::accept('application/json')->withHeaders(
            [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token
            ]
        )->get($this->apiurl . '/productprequisites');
        $data = json_decode($data);
        if ($response->status == 200) {
            $groups = $data->groups;
            $categories = $data->categories;
            $departments = $data->departments;
            $units = $data->units;
            $brands = $data->brands;
            $qualities = $data->qualities;
            $acquiretypes = $data->acquiretypes;
            $agegroups = $data->agegroups;
            $seasons = $data->seasons;
        }
        return view('product.list', compact('attributes', 'brands', 'units', 'departments', 'categories', 'groups', 'seasons', 'acquiretypes', 'qualities', 'agegroups'));
    }
```

**Api**

```
   public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::where('coid', $this->user->coid)->with('group', 'unit', 'category', 'brand', 'department', 'variants','color','size' ,'createdBy')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }
```

is there anyway that i can send yajra pagenumber with my request for pagination